# Geolocalization with Bing and Java

Tags: java, geolocation, bing-api

Can I use the Bing Maps API with Java for geolocation? I have the API key but I can't find anything on the net.

I've found a method with an Excel Macro that works but isn't enough, I need a java console script to do it.

Cheers, Damiano.

Comment: Are you trying to do [geocoding](https://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net/#Geocode) or [reverse geocoding](https://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net/#Reverse%20Geocode)?

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't appear to be any official way to make use of the Maps API in Java.

However, there is an unofficial Java wrapper for the API located [here](https://github.com/IdaDawn/bing-maps-java-sdk). This hasn't been updated in a while, so there's no guarantee it will still work, but it should be a good starting point for implementing geocoding requests.

There is also a method for implementing reverse-geocoding requests in the same wrapper at `client.reverseGeocode()`.

```
import net.virtualearth.dev.webservices.v1.common.GeocodeResult;
import net.virtualearth.dev.webservices.v1.geocode.GeocodeRequest;
import net.virtualearth.dev.webservices.v1.geocode.GeocodeResponse;

import com.google.code.bing.webservices.client.BingMapsWebServicesClientFactory;
import com.google.code.bing.webservices.client.geocode.BingMapsGeocodeServiceClient;
import com.google.code.bing.webservices.client.geocode.BingMapsGeocodeServiceClient.GeocodeRequestBuilder;

public class BingMapsGeocodeServiceSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BingMapsWebServicesClientFactory factory = BingMapsWebServicesClientFactory.newInstance();
        BingMapsGeocodeServiceClient client = factory.createGeocodeServiceClient();
        GeocodeResponse response = client.geocode(createGeocodeRequest(client));
        printResponse(response);
    }

    private static void printResponse(GeocodeResponse response) {
        for (GeocodeResult result : response.getResults().getGeocodeResult()) {
            System.out.println(result.getDisplayName());
        }
    }

    private static GeocodeRequest createGeocodeRequest(BingMapsGeocodeServiceClient client) {
        GeocodeRequestBuilder builder = client.newGeocodeRequestBuilder();
        builder.withCredentials("xxxxxx", null);
        builder.withQuery("1 Microsoft Way, Redmond, WA");
//      builder.withOptionsFilter(Confidence.HIGH);
        return builder.getResult();
    }
}
```